# Live action TV show about battling in another dimension probably using beyblades (or something like that)

Tags: story-identification, tv

There was this old TV show probably released at the end of 2000's or early of 2010's it was about a group of people (probably Asian, don't remember it properly) they had some kind of stones or something. Both the bad group and the good group had these stones. No one knew each other initially.

What used to happen was that whenever a good guy and the a bad guy were close to each other they would be sent to another dimension and they would fight using something, I don't remember what exactly probably something like Beyblade.

Comment: https://youtu.be/vLaaI0PCatU

Comment: Well, liked the video but it isn't what I was looking for.

Comment: There is a Bakugan series that apparently has live action sections. Still tracking down details.

Comment: This one isn't Bakugan. But Bakugan has live action series too!!! Whaaatt!!! I have watched all of its anime but didn't know about live action one.

Comment: Do you remember whether these stones had engravings? Shone with a mystic inner light when used? Were the stones used to summon whatever they fought with?Was this in English? Where were you when you watched this?

Comment: Stones didn't have any engravings. I guess they shined when the other stone handlers were nearby. The stones were only used to transport to the other dimension and it was in English, but definitely dubbed.It was aired in Indian TV.