# Help me find an anime OVA from the 90s

Tags: story-identification, anime

The anime was made in the 90s or 80s, and I guess it was based on the manga.

In Tokyo, two groups of immortals fought: those who wanted to destroy people, and those who decided to protect humanity. Each had unique magical powers: the power of nature, animals or the elements, if I remember correctly. During the battle a barrier was created that would protect the city, but if the main character were to lose and die, the destruction in this zone would be transferred to the real world.
There were also passages at certain points that needed to be destroyed; for example, one of these places was the Tokyo television tower.

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like X - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_(manga)

There was an anime tv series and a movie made about it (where which main character dies in one was reversed in the other)

The general gist was two groups of people had fights aorund Tokyo with magical barriers shifting their battles to some other dimension so reality wasn't damaged.

Can't remember anything about passages needing destroying, but it's been about 25 years since I watched them.

Comment: That’s it! Thanks a lot! I no longer need to suffer with the search for this movie

Answer (score 6):

As per [1990s Anime series where people fought in an alternate dimension. If the good guys won, the area where they fought was undamaged](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/236987/), and amkingTRP's comment, this is likely [Clamp's *X/1999*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_(manga)).

> In 1999, a teenager named Kamui Shirō returns to Tokyo after a six-year absence. He comes to protect those dearest to him, Kotori and Fūma Monou, and fulfill his mother's dying wish of changing fate. The end of the world is fast approaching as superhuman individuals gather and take sides in Tokyo, the battle site of Armageddon. Following Kamui's arrival the Dragons of Heaven and the Dragons of Earth, the two factions in the final battle for humanity's future, vie for the young man's allegiance, convinced his power will assure their victory. The Dragons of Heaven are the first to contact Kamui. The Dragons of Heaven are guided by Hinoto, dreamgazer for the Legislature of Japan. They are the protectors of the kekkai (結界), spiritual barriers (in the form of buildings such as the Tokyo Tower) that hold the fabric of nature together. As long as the kekkai survive, Judgment Day is postponed. The Dragons of Earth are the counterpart to the Dragons of Heaven. Their mission is to destroy the kekkai and unleash earthquakes so the Earth can be cured of the plague of humanity. They were assembled by Hinoto's sister Kanoe, secretary to the Governor of Tokyo.

The good guys can erect "[spiritual barriers](https://xtvclamp.fandom.com/wiki/Spiritual_barriers)" that protect the area they fight in, but only if they win.

> As the barrier fields created by the Dragons of Heaven, the Spirit Shields are fields of varying geometrical shape (depending on which of the Dragons of Heaven has created the Spirit Shield) which only those involved with the end of the world can exist within. The barrier field effectively creates an alternate plane or dimension resembling the area of the material plane which the Spirit Shield was created to protect. This ensures that (so long as the one who created the Spirit Shield remains alive, conscious, in relatively decent health, and maintains an undisclosed amount of concentration required to create the Spirit Shield in the first place) the area in which the Spirit Shield was created and all the ordinary people within it cannot be harmed. Also, as a general rule, it is impossible for even the Dragons of Heaven and Dragons of Earth themselves to leave the space of a Spirit Shield until the creator of the Spirit Shield releases it. Trying to leave a Spirit Shield is said to be extremely painful and dangerous, requiring a great deal of power to even attempt. The rules regarding entering a Spirit Shield, however, seem to be more obscure.
>
> Another way to easily put it is that a Spirit Shield is like a carbon copy of the battlefield combatants can do battle without fear of hurting innocent people or any interference from the outside. If any damage at all occurs in the city inside the Spirit Shield and the one who puts it up lives or kills the other, then no damage will be done to the real location in the primary dimension—as if the battle had never happened. However, if the one who set up the Spirit Shield in the first place gets injured to the point that he or she cannot maintain the requisite concentration to support the Spirit Shield, falls unconscious, or killed altogether, then the Spirit Shield is destroyed, and the damage done to the location within the Spirit Shield during combat is done to the primary physical dimension, killing many innocent bystanders in the vicinity and causing massive destruction.